# multi step registration with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I've gotten the omniauth to work with google by following this [tutorial](http://deepakrip007.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/google-integration-using-devise-and-omniauth-in-rails-app/). The problem I'm currently having is that instead of creating the user when they sign up, I want to route them to a finish registration page where they have to enter additional data. This is similar to how pastebin handles their oauth registration.

UserModel (taken from tutorial):

```
def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = access_token.info
  user = User.where(:provider => access_token.provider, :uid => access_token.uid ).first

  if user
    return user
  else
    registered_user = User.where(:email => access_token.info.email).first

    if registered_user
      return registered_user
    else
      user = User.create(name: data["name"],
      provider:access_token.provider,
      email: data["email"],
      uid: access_token.uid ,
      password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
      )
    end
  end
end
```

omniauthCallBacksController

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController   
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: so? what exactly is the problem. me not understandz

Comment: @phoet the problem is, is that when user registers via google, or facebook, or any 3rd party service, the user is created in the database. What I want to occur is to route the user to a separate page where they complete the registration (add additional information).

Comment: so `new_user_registration_url` is not that page?

Comment: @phoet no, it is not. new_user_registration registers the user. I need to bypass that step and force the user to enter in more information before they can register

Comment: so why don't you change that url to something else?

Comment: @phoet I've actually been trying that for the last day and I haven't been able to get it to work. It seems to ignore that route and just continue with creating the user

Comment: Are you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that your `find_for_google_oauth2` is creating the user.  This means that the `else` in your `google_oauth2` callback isn't getting hit, so it'll never go to your `new_user_registration_url`.  One solution is to separate your find and create steps rather than combining them in `find_for_google_oauth2`.  Then, when the find doesn't find an existing user, you hit your `else` in your `google_oauth2` callback and the omniauth data is put in the session and you get sent to `new_user_registration_url`.  Then once they've entered the extra info and submit the form, you can use that, combined with the omniauth data you saved in the session, to create the user.

Two things about putting the omniauth data in the session:

1. You probably want to pick what you want to keep from the omniauth hash (especially if you're using CookieStore for the session storage) as it's quite large.
2. If you're using the CookieStore and Rails < 4 then the omniauth data being stored in the session (i.e. in the cookie on the user's computer) is unencrypted.